# .NET executes a SQL query and Active Monitor shows multiple rows blocking each other

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, optimization, ado.net, activity-monitor

I use .NET to execute SQL operations on SQL Server 2014, here's the code used:

```cs
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880471/capture-stored-procedure-print-output-in-net
    conn.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(logSqlMessages);
    conn.Open();
    using(SqlCommand stmt = new SqlCommand{
        Connection = conn,
        CommandText = sql,
        CommandTimeout = 30000 // The time in seconds to wait for the command to execute. The default is 30 seconds.
        //,CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    })
    {
        affectedRecords = stmt.ExecuteNonQuery();
    } // using stmt
} // using conn
```

When I look at Active Monitor, there are tens of rows referencing  the same operation. They all have the same `session_id`, some of them have Task State running and most of them are suspended. Some of them have LastWaitTime `CXPACKET` and most are `PAGEIOLATCH_SH`.

I also ran a query on SQL Server and same behavior happened on Active Monitor.

Maybe it's a normal behavior of it, but it's odd that a SELECT operation creates multiple rows and blocks itself like that. Any idea of what may be causing it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Multiple rows in activity monitor for the same SPID means your query has been chosen to be executed in parallel across multiple threads.

[image: NUTS]

Each row on Activity Monitor actually represents one `ECID`, not one `SPID`.

Activity monitor only exposes the `SPID` column (`session_id`), but there is an additional column exposed in [sys.sysprocesses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysprocesses-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) called `ECID` (**E**xecution **C**ontext **ID**) - this is a unique identifier for each thread the query is utilising.

The `sysprocesses` system view is deprecated, but you can find ECID by another name (`exec_context_id`) in the [`sys.dm_os_tasks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-tasks-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) view (as well as other task-related views).

Here is a sample query that captures all of the execution context IDs associated with queries running in a particular session, and what, if anything, they are waiting on:

```
SELECT 
    dot.session_id,
    dot.exec_context_id,
    dot.task_state,
    dowt.wait_type,
    dowt.wait_duration_ms,
    dowt.blocking_session_id,
    dowt.resource_description
FROM sys.dm_os_tasks dot
    LEFT JOIN sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks dowt
        ON  dowt.exec_context_id = dot.exec_context_id
            AND dowt.session_id = dot.session_id
WHERE dot.session_id = 51
ORDER BY exec_context_id;
```

In SQL 2016 two new columns were added to [sys.dm_exec_requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - `DOP` and `parallel_worker_count` - these can be used to check the whether the request is running in parallel or not.

Another key item to note is that the `CXPACKET` wait is inherently a parallelism wait - this by itself tells us the query is using more than one thread.

The `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` is a wait indicating those threads are reading data from disk into memory.